# Create a function, which returns the doubled value of array of integers

Tags: swift

I've just stared learning swift and got stuck with functions. could someone help?

Also, I would be grateful if you could suggest me some books about Swift for beginners with simple exercises so i could practise. Thanks in advance)

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html)

Comment: To change the values of an array, you'd have to use either a loop or the `map` function (see [here](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532) for some more details on the latter).

Comment: I would not recommend `map()` for a beginner. I'd recommend a for loop which help learning basic algorithmic.

Answer (score 1):

There already is such a function. It's called map. It takes a closure that takes each element of the source array as input and returns a new value to use in the output array.

```
let ints = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 23, 57]

let doubled = ints.map { return $0 * 2 }
```

alternately, you could write your own function that takes an array of ints and returns another array of Ints:

```
func doubledInts(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
  var output = [Int]()
  for value in array {
     output.append(value *2)
  }
  return output
}
```

You could also get fancier, and make your function use Generics to take any scalar value (Int and it's variants like Int32, UInt32, Int8, plus Double, Float, etc) and return an array of the same type, but if you don't yet understand the basics of functions then Generics are going to be way over your head.

I learned Swift from the Apple iBook "The Swift Programming Language." I found it very informative, but your milage may vary.

Comment: Like @Larme said, I'd not suggest starting out with `.map` either as it's hard to understand its logic when you're not familiar with the very basics.